# What is this hole in some gas related threads

Tags: piping, compressed-gases, connectors

What are those holes for? (Those are for CO<sub>2</sub>.)

Here are a few examples :

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Isn't using picture you can find everywhere on the net as example, a case of fair use ?

Comment: It's fair use if fair creditation is given. Someone else went to the trouble and expense of creating it. Anyway, they're the site rules.

Comment: At some point we need to be realist : Both those pictures are published identically on multiple sites on the net and none of them credit the author which is probably an anonymous chinese firm who created it, only because it would allow sellers to sell their product, which does not even bear any company name on it. Now, how do you decide who is to be credited ? At some point, one must admit that the maker of the product just wants the money for selling his product and not being annoyed with public relations and author creditation - and the picture must be treated as public domain.

Comment: We are not a sales site.  It is not their rules, but ours.  In many cases we follow the links to get a better idea of the background of the question.

Comment: You missed the point : As I mentioned, since this product is sold by multiple vendors AND I couldn't find any one which disclose the maker of the product or the owner of the picture AND there is no logo on the product itself... I do not know and I believe it is impossible to know who owns this picture. No one should be expected to do impossible things. About following the link, I simply tried to find the source by right clicking the picture, and click "search image with google"

Comment: By the way, since this seems to be a problem, I escalated it on meta : https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/we-might-need-to-be-more-accurate-about-the-limits-of-creditation-and-plagiarism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are pressure relief ports. The threads you have pictured are parallel type and are used without PTFE tape on CO<sub>2</sub> drink carbonators such as Sodastream brand. The gas-tight seal is made by the O-ring and not by the threads.

Without the vent hole there is a risk of the bottle being blown off by residual pressure when the thread disengages. With the vent hole gas is vented once the O-ring seal is "broken". Additionally, if the gas supply has not turned off (perhaps by sticking valve in the top of the CO<sub>2</sub> cylinder) the user will receive an audible warning.

[image]

*Figure 1. The gaps in the thread of a PET carbonated drinks bottle and cap serve a similar function and release the pressure before disengaging the threads. This prevents injury due to caps being shot off the bottle otherwise. Image source: [Miho.de](https://www.miho.de/en/products/pet-returnable-bottles/).*

Comment: In the case of pet carbonated drinks, there is another reason, which is that more than preventing injuries, it reduces the risk of ejecting most of the content as foam if the gaz expands in one shot, But otherwise, it makes sense. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is called a weep hole for the upper fitting, intended to help detect abnormal leakage.  Since the fluid should be contained in the internal sections, the fluid should not be present mid thread deep if seals are functioning.  By routing it outside where one might observe or to a point that has a sensor, it gives indications that the sealing system has failed.

See for example
[What's Up With That Tiny Hole](https://www.dynexhydraulics.com/coned-threaded-hydraulic-fittings-a-primer.)

On the lower valve, I can't say for certain that it isn't some type of additional sense or vent port that has to do with affecting the valve based on whether the device is properly connected, over pressurized, etc or not- a bit more active a variant of the humble weep hole where what I had called a leak before might instead indicate a proper connection.

A hole can serve different functions on each part. Observing only one end might not tell us the hole story.